# JQuery UI Datepicker, reverse the order of the year in the dropdowns

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker with changeyear: true. The 'year' drop down displays the title as 2009, then instead of the next year below the title being 2008, 2007, 2006 and so on it starts at 1999 and counts upwards. I can't seem to find an easy solution to reverse this order?

Comment: I really hate the poor usability on dropdowns for selecting years and generally recommend avoiding them. Here's why: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20001112.html.

Comment: This is inside a calendar popup, it actually gives the the user three options, either type it themselves (which is recommended in that article), select it from a popup calendar or use the drop down to select the year. Im pretty sure that is a usable solution!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend editing the original ui.datepicker.js as [Cuong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210953/cuong-quach) suggested because your changes will be lost as soon as you or another developer replaces the file when a new version is released. Remembering what customisations have been made in order to re-apply is not practical. Instead, you can override the existing `_generateMonthYearHeader` method in your own separate JS like so:

```
// store original so we can call it inside our overriding method
$.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader_original = $.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader;

$.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader = function(inst, dm, dy, mnd, mxd, s, mn, mns) {
  var header = $($.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader_original(inst, dm, dy, mnd, mxd, s, mn, mns)),
      years = header.find('.ui-datepicker-year');

  // reverse the years
  years.html(Array.prototype.reverse.apply(years.children()));

  // return our new html
  return $('<div />').append(header).html();
}
```

I just wrote this for something I'm working on and it does the trick nicely :)

Comment: // Add the below if condition. Other wise the year is not displayed when not a dropdown.
    if(years.is('select'))
      years.html(Array.prototype.reverse.apply(years.children()));

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to hack the plugin without ripping it is assigning a event handler to the year select item.

```
//Hack for reverting year order
$(document.body).delegate('select.ui-datepicker-year', 'mousedown', function() {
  (function(sel) {
    var el = $(sel);
    var ops = $(el).children().get();
    if ( ops.length > 0 && $(ops).first().val() < $(ops).last().val() ) {
      $(el).empty();
      $(el).html(ops.reverse());
    }
  })(this);
});
```

This code must work fine! :P

Answer (score 6):

There is a "way" to get the year started from the last date:

```
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
changeMonth: true, 
changeYear: true,  
yearRange: "-70:", 
maxDate: "-13Y"
```

Instead if using `yearRange` as fixed years `yearRange: "1900:-13"`  it's better to use this from bottom up: `"-70:"`, and set the `maxDate`.  Now I get my year select box starting from 2004 and not 1900.

P.S: All the other solutions have been tested. They are very slow, and some don't work so well (especially the old ones - sets current year instead of 2004 for example).

Answer (score 4):

- Open the file `ui.datepicker.js`
- Find the method `_generateMonthYearHeader: function(inst, drawMonth, drawYear, minDate, maxDate, selectedDate, secondary, monthNames, monthNamesShort)`
- Find the following loop in the method

  ```
  for (; year <= endYear; year++) {
      html += '<option value="' + year + '"' +
          (year == drawYear ? ' selected="selected"' : '') +
          '>' + year + '</option>';
  }

  html += '</select>';
  ```
- Insert the following code before that loop:

  ```
  if (year-100 < 1900) // Check year is lower then 1900
      year = 1950;     // change start point of above loop, it helps you having the 
                       // year's dropdownlist starting at 1950, and ending of current year plus 10.
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I have an answer to you, but it's not exactly what you may want to hear.

After searching the internet for a solution that would reverse the order of the years in the dropdown, I have come to this:

```
{
    changeMonth: true
    , changeYear: true
    , yearRange: '-65:'
    , maxDate: '1999/12/31'
}
```

This will have the maxdate preselected, and therefore choosing a year you will automatically see the last entry, thereby being able to scroll *up* to choose an earlier date.

Edit: yearRange is added arbitrarily, to create a starting point 65 years ago. maxDate is also chosen arbitrarily, as a date 12 years prior to writing this comment. Basically this menu will allow someone to choose an age between 12 and 65 years.

It's not ideal, but it works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first line of the `for` loop with:

```
var minYear = year;
year = endYear;
for (; year >= minYear; year--) {
```