# sort years in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

By default, in a jquery datepicker years are shown like this:
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011

and I want them to be sorted ascendent:
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007

I'm using google's online jquery, so I can't change anything in the code. any idea on how to change the type of sorting? I haven't found a parameter to pass the type of sorting.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

May be duplicate of

[JQuery UI Datepicker, reverse the order of the year in the dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns)

Answer (score 0):

`and I want them to be sorted ascendent: 2011 2010 2009 2008 2007`

That's descending, no ascending.

`I'm using google's online jquery, so I can't change anything in the code.`

Your page code does not run from google servers, you're simply loading jQuery (et al) from them

[JQuery UI Datepicker, reverse the order of the year in the dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns)

Comment: sorry, I wanted to say desdending.