# Jquery date picker year order

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have this code here for a Jquery date picker

```
// Datepicker from jQuery UI plugin
    $birth.datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
        $gender.focus();
    },
        yearRange: '1950:2006',
        changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,           
    showOtherMonths: true,          
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

My year dropdown starts at 1950 and goes all the way to 2006, I would like to reverse them..

I tried `yearRange: '2006:1950'` but nothing displayed :(

Is there away to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

The link supplied is a good solution.  Here is another way that is kind of a hack but works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sSdUbqd1pWKyiBOZAMwD?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var showPicker = false;

  $("#txtBirthday").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
      $gender.focus();
    },
    yearRange: '1950:2006',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      showPicker = false;
    }
  });

  $(".ui-datepicker").on("mouseenter", function() {

    if (!showPicker) {
      showPicker = true;

      //Reverse the years
      var dropYear = $("select.ui-datepicker-year");

      dropYear.find('option').each(function() {
        dropYear.prepend(this);
      });

    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this heps, I found a nicer solution and came across your post. If this is still relevant:

[jQuery datepicker year dropdown starts from 1900 and I want it to start from the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650410/jquery-datepicker-year-dropdown-starts-from-1900-and-i-want-it-to-start-from-the/42666011#42666011)

> This is how I solved my problem.  and I think this is why jQuery
>   aren't fixing this "Bug" because there is a "way" to get the year
>   started from the last date:
>
> ```
> dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
> changeMonth: true, 
> changeYear: true,  
> yearRange: "-70:", 
> maxDate: "-13Y"
> ```
>
> In comparison to my original code posted here, instead if using
>   `yearRange` as fixed years `yearRange: "1900:-13"`  it's better to use
>   this from bottom up: `"-70:"`. and set the `maxDate`.  So now I get my
>   year select box starting from 2004 and not 1900.
>
> Hope this helps others out there.
>
> P.S: All the other solutions have been tested. They are very slow, and
>   some don't work so well (especially the old ones - sets current year
>   instead of 2004 for example).