# jQuery datepicker year dropdown starts from 1900 and I want it to start from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker on my website and I have it set like this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( 
    { 
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',  
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true,  
        yearRange: "1900:-13" 
    } 
).on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
    // '$(this)' refers to '$("#datepicker")'
});
```

So my year select bar enables years 1900 and up to 2004.

By default when opening the year selectbox - it starts from 1900 and I have to scroll a lot for a more relevant year.

How can I set my jQuery datepicker to start from 2004 (scrolling up) and not from 1900 (scrolling *a lot* down)?

Researching this issue leads to old posts (7 years ago) and I might be able to find a more practical solution that works for these days.

Comment: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5774 Only been open for 7 years

Comment: @epascarello no seriously :X

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697315/jquery-date-picker-year-order or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns

Comment: Guess you could prefill the textbox with 01/01/2004 (mm/dd/yyyy) and have the user change it?

Comment: @epascarello If this interests you - I found a nice solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    currentText: "Now"
});
```

I think that modifying `currenText` value you can achieve what you want.

[API docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-currentText)

Comment: this doesn't work if your date starts at 2004 
When selected 2004 it will output 2017

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've made a huge mistake. I want to point you on `defaultDate ` instead of currentText.. try to set `defaultDate
: 01/01/2004` into date picker options like suggested for currentText.. if it works I'll update my answer