# datepicker widget is not showing year in downward sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using following code to have datepicker for my form for birthday field,

```
<script>
                $(function() {
                    $( "#newsletter_birthday" ).datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: "1940:2013"
                    });                     
                });
            </script>
```

Currently its working but is showing year in ascending order i want it to show in descending order, any idea how we do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns

Comment: Did you try reversing the date range as "2013:1940" ?

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-revere-year-range-order

Comment: @Nelson Menezes ya i did that trick no possible

Comment: @Vanga Sasidhar im newbie to jquery can you tell me how we can override the js file,since when i go to the solution given by you, overriding the js file is suggesting this trick ,any idea as to how to override js file

Comment: Use this solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12356777/986141 Add the given code in your JavaScript file and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you ,
The same they discussed here.

[JQuery UI Datepicker, reverse the order of the year in the dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns)