# datepicker show the year in reverse order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                      firstDay: 0, // set first day of week as monday
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true,
                      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                      showButtonPanel: true,
                      showOtherMonths: true,

beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
  // Get the current year
  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

  // it only show the 2023 on dropdown listbox
  var yearRange = "";
  for (var i = currentYear; i >= 2010; i--) {
    yearRange += i + ":";
  }
  yearRange = yearRange.slice(0, -1);

  // Set the year range
  inst.settings.yearRange = yearRange;
  }
 });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I need to show the year range in reverse order in datapicker. I need to show (2023,2022...2010) However it doesn't work, my code show (2010, 2011,...2023).
I search the web and tried these methods. I used jQuery JavaScript Library v3.6.4. Would someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

The below code  only shows the 2023 on dropdown listbox

```
$(function () {
            $(calID, window.opener)
                  .datepicker(
                  {
                      firstDay: 0, // set first day of week as monday
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true,
                      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                      showButtonPanel: true,
                      showOtherMonths: true,

beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
  // Get the current year
  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

  // it only show the 2023 on dropdown listbox
  var yearRange = "";
  for (var i = currentYear; i >= 2010; i--) {
    yearRange += i + ":";
  }
  yearRange = yearRange.slice(0, -1);

  // Set the year range
  inst.settings.yearRange = yearRange;
  }
 });
});
```

The below code show year range is not in reverse order:

```
$(function () {
            $(calID, window.opener)
                  .datepicker(
                  {
                      firstDay: 0, // set first day of week as monday
                      changeMonth: true,
                      changeYear: true,
                      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                      showButtonPanel: true,
                      showOtherMonths: true,
                      
                      beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                       var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
                      inst.settings.yearRange = "2010:" + currentYear;

                      // Set the reverse year range; I found that the current jquery.Ui doesn't has reverseYearRange.

                      inst.settings.reverseYearRange = true;
                      }
     });
 });
```

Comment: What is `inst.settings.` ? ... it may be better if you can compose a basic fiddle example by using the `<>` icon on the text editor toolbar. You will need to add CDN's to the jqueryui things as part of the html.

Comment: @PaulT. I added the example

Comment: I just checked the source code, apparently it is impossible: if you specify year range backwards e.g. 2023:2010 then a Math.max corrects it to 2023:2023. The loop that creates the <options> only goes forward. The workaround is to use jQuery to reverse the items on change month year. Or monkey patch the source code.

Comment: found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594894/jquery-ui-datepicker-reverse-the-order-of-the-year-in-the-dropdowns